# IOS: How to put some view on top of presented modal view controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, uiview

I have an activity view that I have added in AppDelegate class to tap bar:

```
[self.mainTabBar.view addSubview: spinner];
```

When there are connection problems it is visible in each view controller and is spinning.
There is some button at certain view controller, makes to present some modal view controller.
That modal view controller overlaps the spinner. How to make that spinner always be on top of all views or at least on top of that modal view controller?
I tried to make such a thing in view controller that presents modal view controller:

```
[self presentModalViewController:selectionViewController animated:YES];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:[self.tabBarController.view viewWithTag:15]];
```

Not works.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Add the view to the main window.

```
UIWindow* mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[mainWindow addSubview: spinner];
```

Comment: Although this won't respond to orientation changes correctly.  For that you need to use  something like UIView* view = mainWindow.subviews[0]; [view addSubview:spinner];

Comment: You just solved my (a bit unrelated) problem, thanks!

Comment: Ok, but how to remove it from another procedure, @phix23?

Comment: @new2ios you could tag the view with a unique id to find it again in the view hierarchy of the window

Comment: Best answer on stackoverflow

Answer (score 12):

While phix23's answer is correct, here is a more complete example:

```
//The view you want to present
UIViewController *viewControllerYouWantToPresentOnTop = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

//Create transparent host view for presenting the above view
UIWindow* mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
UIViewController *viewControllerForPresentation = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[[viewControllerForPresentation view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[[viewControllerForPresentation view] setOpaque:FALSE];
[mainWindow addSubview:[viewControllerForPresentation view]];

//Make your transparent view controller present your actual view controller
[viewControllerForPresentation presentViewController:viewControllerYouWantToPresentOnTop animated:TRUE];
```

Remember to clean up after yourself when you don't need these any longer.

This code can be used from anywhere in your app, even a library :)

Comment: Best I've found so far, but this causes `unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for`.

Comment: @meaning-matters Do you have any other animations going on at the same time? You may want to wait for them to finish.

Comment: No other animations I'm afraid. Thanks for responding quickly @Maciej.

Comment: Try this UIViewController *viewControllerYouWantToPresentOnTop = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; instead of the first line

Comment: @MaciejSwic: Where do you use `viewControllerYouWantToPresentOnTop`? Is that the `navigationController` reference at the bottom, or is that something else?

Comment: @LawrenceKesteloot i forgot to rename navigationController to viewControllerYouWantToPresentOnTop in my snippet, fixed it now.

Comment: This was the one for which I was looking for more than 6 hours. Really solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

An app normally displays its content within a single window throughout its life.
But there are situations where an extra window may be used to add content on top of everything else. Apple ensures `UIAlertView` always stays on top by adding it in a separate window.

```
UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame];
contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,contentFrame.size.width, contentFrame.size.height)];
window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
[window addSubview:contentView];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Show and hide your window by setting `window.hidden = Yes or No` as needed.
This will always show your `contentView` on top of everything else in the app.

Answer (score 1):

The modal controller is in a completely different layer, you cannot make any subview of the presenting controller to overlap it.

Use a `UIAlertView` with a spinner inside. The alerts are displayed in a layer which overlaps even modal controllers.

Comment: This is not true. While alert views are in a separate layer on top of everything else, modals are not and can be overridden using the code i posted below.

Comment: @MaciejSwic I know how to add subviews to window, note that my answer was stating `any subview of the presenting controller`. Using `UIAlertView` is technically a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Place the view to the keyWindow, as suggested above. You might also need to set Presentation style of the modal view as Current Context, otherwise, it can still pop on top

Comment: The other answers are not always "above". Sure, they are while you type your answer - but then they're sorted in the page once posted. Criteria are "Trending", "Highest score", "Date modified", "Date created". Your answer will be placed in the page according to this parameter.