# How to present modal view controller from library?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a library that must present a modal view.  How do I find the top most visible `UIViewController` to call `presentViewController` on?  My current app has a table view controller, navigation controllers, and other modal views.

The best I could find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13469847/1971013), but this results in `unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UIViewController: 0x...>` followed by a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.  (This was when there was another modal view controller at top.)

Comment: Have you tried this especially 2nd answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131205/iphone-how-to-find-topmost-view-controller? Otherwise it might be better just to have your own overlay UIWindow.