# How do I add a UIView as a subview of the topmost view without knowing which view it is?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, subview

I want to add a view:

```
[aView addSubview:myNewView];
```

What I am trying to do is find what view is the topmost view being displayed at any given moment, so I can dynamically add a view on top of it. For example, let's say my view stack looks like this:

1. Modal Camera View (on top of everything, currently being displayed)
2. TabView
3. Navigation View
4. View
5. TableView

I want to dynamically put something on top of whatever view is at 0.

Does anyone know how to do this or if it's even possible?

Comment: [self.view subviews] returns an NSArray. You can access the view at index 0 by [self.view subviewAtIndex:0];

Comment: Do you mean in general, or are you specifically trying to overlay a view ontop of the view from a `UIImagePickerController`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view hierarchy is not represented by a stack but by a tree, so there is nothing as `the topmost view`.

If you just want to add a view on top of all other views, add it to `UIWindow` as done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859420/ios-how-to-put-some-view-on-top-of-presented-modal-view-controller) :

```
UIWindow* mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[mainWindow addSubview:myNewView];
```

If by view you really meant view controller, then I don't think there way to "walk" the current stack because it would depend on the classes of the stacked view controllers, and also for the same reason as the view hierachy: a view controller could have many childs - a `UITabBarController` for example.